# Consultar datos de una tabla pivote

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

Muy buenas tardes tengo una pequeña duda tengo 2 tablas una de registros y una de vehículos, ya realice la inserción de los datos pero no busco la manera de obtener la información que esta relacionada por ejemplo mi tabla de registros puede tener muchas unidades entonces quiero obtener la lista o el conjunto de unidades que están relacionadas al registro con id 1.

```
$modelo = $this->repository->find($id);
return $modelo->vehiculos;
```

Si ejecuto retorno esa funcion me trae los siguientes datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después leyendo la documentación me percato que se hace un foreach para recorrer y traer la información que deseas de la relación la cuestión que cuando retorno el foreach solo me trae la primera relación y cuando lo paso a mi vista por medio de un compact me aparece la ultima relación me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Publicá el código de los modelos, del `foreach()` que mencionás y del controlador desde donde llamás a la vista.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder ya pude solucionarlo